# SQL How to check whether all values inside a groupy by are different and then return them all?

Tags: sql

A similar question to one asked by me but a bit differenet

In this case, for a specific ID (that is not unique) I have these values:

```
ID      | Timestamp | Value
id11111 | DATE1     | Value1
id11111 | DATE1     | Value1
id11111 | DATE2     | **Value2**
id11111 | DATE2     | **Value1**
id22222 | DATE1     | Value3
id22222 | DATE1     | Value3
id22222 | DATE1     | Value3
```

My objective would be to return the following table:

```
ID      | Timestamp | Value
id11111 | DATE2     | Value2
id11111 | DATE2     | Value1
```

Since there are rows where for X Timestamp and Y ID, the value is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.timestamp = t.timestamp and
                    t2.value <> t.value
             );
```

With window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(value) over (partition by id, timestamp) as min_value,
             max(value) over (partition by id, timestamp) as max_value
      from t
     ) t
where min_value <> max_value
```